# Disable indicator-datetime-service pop ups

Tags: 17.04, indicator, evolution

I got a new computer and installed Ubuntu 17.04 on it. I use evolution to connect with Exchange server and it works really well and integrates with the whole system beautifully. For example, I can clik the the time indicator and the system will show me the calendar and a few upcoming events, taken straight from the Evolution's calendar.

However, 17.04 brought something additional - 15 minutes before a calendar event, together with evolution reminder window, indicator-datetime-service alert pops up:

[image]

It's super annoying, not only it's a duplicated information, but it also plays a really disturbing sound. How to disable these pop-ups? Without losing all other event-integration features (like the list of upcoming events in the time indicator that I mentioned before)?

Comment: I had assumed this was part of "Evolution" but removing Evolution doesn't seem to stop the pop-ups from happening. It's really annoying.

Comment: @BaronGrivet I may have found something. Try executing `gsettings set com.ubuntu.notifications.settings:/com/ubuntu/NotificationSettings/com.ubuntu.calendar/calendar/ enable-notifications false` and see if it helps (I'm not yet sure if it does the job). You can also try reading the value with `get` before setting it, I didn't do it and I don't know what was the default value.

Comment: cheers, I've done that. Will see if it shuts the damn thing up.

Comment: that seems to have worked, thank you. You should put it down as your answer.

Comment: @BaronGrivet Thanks, will do this tomorrow (I need to be 100% sure that it works also for me) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't easy to find an answer, since this feature is completely undocumented, but I did it. I had to download the source code of the [`indicator-datetime`](https://launchpad.net/indicator-datetime) and find some code related to this alert. A few quick searches for `service` and `notification` led me to a variable called `cal_notification_enabled` and two constants:

- `SETTINGS_NOTIFY_CALENDAR_PATH`- `/com/ubuntu/NotificationSettings/com.ubuntu.calendar/calendar/`
- `SETTINGS_NOTIFY_ENABLED_KEY` - `enable-notifications`

`dconf-editor` wasn't helpful as I couldn't find this parameter there, but a quick Google Search [unveiled the truth](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg22690.html). This functionality is somewhat important in Ubuntu Phone and it can be switched on and off in the calendar app. On desktop, however, there's no switch for it in calendar's settings and it seems that it's `true` by default. It can be disabled from console though:

`gsettings set com.ubuntu.notifications.settings:/com/ubuntu/NotificationSettings/com.ubuntu.calendar/calendar/ enable-notifications false`

After switching this setting to false no alerts will disturb your work.